# Something wrong with django json serializer

Tags: json, django, ajax

i try looking for answers but so far to no avail, basically i try to return django model as json however, it seem that the serializer convert it to string instead

my code is as follow:

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from screener.models import maintable
from .models import Messages
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
from datetime import datetime
import json

def infiniteScroll(request, room_name):
    dateFilter=request.GET.get('date')
    dateFilter=dateFilter[5:len(dateFilter)-4]
    dateFilter=datetime.strptime(dateFilter, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
    data=serializers.serialize('json', reversed(Messages.objects.filter(room=room_name).filter(date_added__lt=dateFilter).order_by('-date_added')[:2]))
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='chat'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
    path('<str:room_name>/hist/', views.infiniteScroll, name='infiniteScroll'),
]
```

when i go to the site http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/AAPL/hist/?date=Thu,%2023%20Sep%202021%2014:03:42%20GMT

the result is a page with string instead:

```
"[{\"model\": \"chat.messages\", \"pk\": 118, \"fields\": {\"username\": \"adiputra12\", \"room\": \"AAPL\", \"content\": \"hello\", \"date_added\": \"2021-09-23T13:54:30.043Z\"}}]"
```

how can I return json instead like shown below:

```
[{'model': 'chat.messages', 'pk': 118, 'fields': {'username': 'adiputra12', 'room': 'AAPL', 'content': 'hello', 'date_added': '2021-09-23T13:54:30.043Z'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After This line of code

```
data=serializers.serialize('json',reversed(Messages.objects.filter(room=room_name).filter(date_added__lt=dateFilter).order_by('-date_added')[:2]))
```

Try adding

```
data = json.loads(data)
return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Println i realize my mistake i try that before data = json.loads(data) but i put a typo data = json.load(data)... it work greta now thank you